# CUDA inefficient access pattern to global memory

Tags: caching, cuda

I coded a CUDA kernel that performs an array addition of two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`. The information, which index of `arr1` should be added with which index of `arr2` is stored in an array `idx`.

Here is a code example:

```
__global__ add(float* arr1, float* arr2, int* idx, int length)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    // each thread performs (length) additions,
    // arr2 is (lenght) times larger than arr1
    for (int j=threadIdx.x; j<length*blockDim.x; j+=blockDim.x)
    {
        arr1[i] += arr2[ idx[blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + j] ]; // edited here
    }
}
```

The code yields the correct output, though is hardly faster than a openmp-parallel code on the CPU with 8 threads. I tried this for different block-sizes.

I suspect that the access pattern to `arr2` is inefficient, since `arr2` is in global memory and is accessed quasi-randomly -- the array `idx` contains unique, sorted, but non-contiguous indices (could be 2, 3, 57, 103, ...). Therefor, the L1 cache is not taken advantage of.
Also, the arrays are very large and cannot entirely fit in shared memory.

Is there any way around this obstacle? 
Do you have an idea on how to optimize the access pattern to `arr2`?

Comment: What makes you think access to `arr2` is the bottleneck? What about the completely uncoalesced acceess to `idx`?

Comment: Good Point. Still, one thread at least accesses `length` contiguous elements of `idx`, whereas there is no order in the access pattern of `arr2` whatsoever.

Comment: I think you need to read about memory coalescing

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did some research and updated the question. The access to `idx` should now be coalesced and my code runs twice as fast. Now I'm pretty sure that the access to `arr2` is the bottleneck.

Comment: There is no way that the edited code could produce the same results as the original in your question

Comment: Well, I resorted `idx` accordingly.

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: The execution time decreased from about 40ms to about 23 ms in my example. Now, as I understand it, the access to `idx` is optimized. It remains the quasi-random access to `arr2`. As resorting `arr2` would be very unpractical (there is another algorithm in my code that expects `arr2` in a certain order), I fear there is no solution, is there?

Comment: You could try binding `arr2` to a texture and see what happens.

Comment: Would then `arr2` be stored in texture memory? Then, I would need to successively load chunks of `arr2` into it, since the array is huge. Anyway, the problem has been solved -- thank you for your efforts!

Comment: There is no such thing as texture memory, just textures. But the difference is that texture units have their own cache which is designed to improve performance for data with strong spatial locality. That might be the case with your data. Alternatively, in spatially distributed problems graph partitioning of data to decompose in sub-domains can also increase performance. But at a one-time computation expense. But all of this requires much more knowledge of your specific application that you have provided in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you can try doing here:

- Global memory is slow you can try loading the arrays to shared memory for each block. So you would load the array partially for each block for example.
- If there is anything that is defined as constant you should move that to the constant memory.
- Try unrolling the loop.
- Definitely try launching multiple kernels with different stream parameters as well as different block/thread combinations.

Hope this gives you an idea on your way to optimization :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Successively copying chunks of `arr2` to shared memory and operating on that did significantly speed up the execution time.

Comment: You can also try unrolling the loop with #pragma unroll that should speed up a little bit. Dividing up the kernel to have concurrent kernel executions in different streams would also speed it up but will cost your precious development time :)

Comment: The bottleneck of my application now lies somewhere else, the cuda kernel is more than fast enough now. But just out of interest, I will try your suggestions ;)

Comment: Use the Profile Cuda Application on nsight -> start performance analysis in visual studio. Run all the cuda experiments, that will help you find out your application bottleneck. Good luck!